# Heirarchical Select Steps Drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6

I am working on a site in which there is two type of user- 'Company' and 'Consultant'. I am using content profile and auto assign role for this. in the registration of consultant i have a field to select main area and sub area (for ex-Science and Technology[as Main Area] and Biology and medicine[as Sub Area]). I want to use Hierarchical select but I am doing something wrong so it is not working.

So please either tell me the steps of Hierarchical Select or suggest me another module for this.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your tpl whether you are using one.

```
<div style="display:none">
<?php print drupal_render($form) ?>
</div>
```

I use the same modules and it works.